# How to use node key?

Tags: subkey, node-key

I have a local node with validators Alice and Bob. I've created a node key using this command

```bash
subkey generate-node-key --file ./.keys/node-key
```

Can I use the node key with `--validator`? Because I saw an example creating a node with only node key and validators connecting that node. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the `--validator` flag and the `--node-key` or `--node-key-file` at the same time. Keep in mind that the `--node-key` will have precedence over the other one.

Note if you are using the `--alice` or `--bob` flags, the `--validator` flag is not required.

Additionally, you can also use the node itself to generate the same identity instead of using subkey like:

```bash
./target/release/node-template key generate-node-key

# Local Identity
12D3KooWJHhnF64TXSmyxNkhPkXAHtYNRy86LuvGQu1LTi5vrJCL
# Node Key
86e77fbcc353717cd95cb8861f6763b250384af1289bd45f24b0a477f620fc5b
```

or save it to a file:

```
./target/release/node-template key generate-node-key --file ./.keys/node-key
```

Then, you can run the node like:

```bash
# Using the node key directly (only for dev)
./target/release/node-template --validator --node-key 86e77fbcc353717cd95cb8861f6763b250384af1289bd45f24b0a477f620fc5b
```

or

```bash
# Using the file
./target/release/node-template --validator --node-key-file ./.keys/node-key
```

And when the node is running, you'll see that the node identity is the same as the one generated by the node or subkey

```bash
2022-08-28 17:21:09   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWJHhnF64TXSmyxNkhPkXAHtYNRy86LuvGQu1LTi5vrJCL
```

Answer (score 3):

The node key is the identity of your node.

When you boot the node, you will get that too.

It will be stored at `<DATA-DIR>/chains/<CHAIN>/network/secret_ed25519`.

There are many ways to use it.

1. put it in that folder
2. replace the existing file's content
3. `./node --node-key-file /path-to-the-node-key`

Just a note here.

I generally don't generate the node key from the `subkey`.

You just need to run `./node --node-key-file a'.

If the `a` does not exist, the node will automatically create an `a` node key file.