# How to use custom keys for parachain collator instead of predefined Alice or Bob?

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, substrate-parachain-template, subkey, node-key

There is example how to use Alice predefined account to run

```
./target/release/parachain-template-node \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain ../polkadot/raw-local-chainspec.json \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977
```

How to specify my custom sercet-key or seed phrase?

Comment: Dupe of https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4477/how-to-use-node-key Please refer to the answers contained on this link.

Comment: @BernardoRodrigues afaik the node-key is always `ed25519` but when I look at the chain spec I see a function `get_collator_keys_from_seed` which has a single line : `get_from_seed::<AuraId>(seed)`. I am confused, when we use the `--alice` option, is this function being called as the name would suggest `get_collator_keys_from_seed` ? If yes, I should expect the `node-key` to expect a `sr25519` key but when I used `//Alice`'s `sr25519` key instead, the node errored out with cannot parse as `ed25519`. So where does the `ed25519` key live/get inserted when using `--alice` option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom key you need to add for collator is `Aura` key, which is of format `sr25519`, which are already defined in the `chain_spec.rs` of parachain-template for Alice and Bob, what you need to do is to add the `sr25519` in the `customSpec.json` of the parachain node for custom collator and add it via the `insert_key` rpc to the node. You can also refer to this [How to properly set session keys for Relay and Parachain with custom keys](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/how-to-properly-set-session-keys-for-relay-and-parachain-with-custom-keys)